# How can the disable file operation, file selection and filter panel from JFileChooser(JAVA Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, view, jfilechooser

I need to embed `JFileChooser` dialogbox in a `Panel`. I only need the file and folder view. How can I disable others panel that are included in `dialogBox` i.e(file operation, file selection and filter panel) from `JFileChooser()` `dialogBox`..

Thank you

Comment: I have been able to disable the open/cancel button panel but still other remains.
FileSystemView view=null;
 JFileChooser jfc= new JFileChooser();
 fc.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);

Comment: I have been able to disable the open/cancel button panel but still other remains.            
  FileChooser jfc= new JFileChooser();
  jfc.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into using a [`JTree`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) to display the file structure.

It is fairly easy to convert a File structure into an implementation of a [`TreeModel`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html).

Basically I would begin by making a class called `FileTreeModel`.

Then, you can use the top level directory as the root of the Model and go from there.

Then, all you need to do is set the `TreeModel` of a `JTree` to that of your `FileTreeModel`.

The code for the `FileTreeModel` may look something like this:

```
private File root;
public TreeModel(File root){
    this.root = root;
}

public boolean isLeaf(Object node){
    File f = (File) node;
    return !f.isDirectory();
}
```

You will need to implement the rest of the interface.  But it is fairly simple.